# ie not firing ajax complete call on certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

even with a piece of code like this

```
$.get('getforums.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

works well in chrome, firefox, safari, opera but not this baby.
tried everything, cleared cache, recreate this file in different editor,
even make this file just echoed a 's', but no,
it just don't like this file, works perfect on other file

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an encoding issue. IE is pretty strict about what encodings it will accept. Try switch the $.get out for a $.ajax call and log the error message.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getforums.php',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: you're fixing IE, don't use `console.log()`

Comment: Hah true. Just include firebug lite before you start then :)

Comment: Firebug Lite will interfere with your callbacks - I recommend you avoid it like the plague when diagnosing this kind of issue.